# Watch not showing subshell output

Tags: watch, streams

Why does the following not output "hello" line?

```
watch bash -c 'echo hello'
```

As this one?

```
watch 'echo hello'
```

I expected to have `echo` write to `bash` output directly and this to be read by `watch` and formatted to terminal. Does `bash -c` not use `stdout`?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use double-quotes like this :

```
watch "bash -c 'echo hello'"
```

Or, the other way around:

```
watch 'bash -c "echo hello"'
```

Comment: But why? Does bash not receive "echo hello" command, but "echo" for example?

Comment: Exactly ! You can add `-x` to `bash` to see what it is doing.